# Как решить проблему параллакса с кроссбраузерностью?

Tags: php, css, кроссбраузерность

Всем привет!
Есть вот [такая страничка](http://www.skolametropol.cz/russian-courses.php), на которой присутствует (должен присутствовать) параллакс картинки. 
В Safari 9.0 и в Firefox 38.0.5 параллакс работает, а в Chrome 44.0 и Opera 30.0 - не работает. Сайт в IE 8,9,10 я даже боюсь открывать.
Код параллакса в CSS:

```
.rus {
background: url(img/redsquare.jpg) no-repeat center center;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding: 30px 0;
```

}

В PHP параллакс обвернут в section:

```
<section class="rus ruover">
<div class="section-title text-light"><h2>Nabízíme níže uvedené typy jazykových kurzů:
    <!-- <span>but <em>design</em> 'aint one</span> --></h2>
</div>
<!-- <a href="#portfolio" class="down-arrow-btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a> -->
```

Эту проблему уже давно не могу решить. По-любому, где-то туплю. 
Ребят, подскажите в чём может заключаться корень проблемы?
Спасибо!